# How to Prove Asymptotic Notations

Tags: algorithm, big-o, notation

I want to prove the following statement

```
2^(⌊lg n⌋+⌈lg n⌉)∕n ∈ Θ(n)
```

I know that to prove it, we have to find the constants `c1>0`, `c2>0`, and `n0>0` such that

```
c1.g(n) <= f(n) <= c2.g(n) for all n >= n0
```

In other words, we have to prove `f(n) <= c.g(n) and f(n) >= c.g(n)`.

The problem is how to prove the left hand side `(2^(⌊lg n⌋+⌈lg n⌉)∕n)`

Thank you

Comment: Is this question inspired by a homework assignment?  If so, please add the [homework] tag.

Comment: What do you mean by proving a statement> Only theorems have proof, what theorem is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by expanding the exponential. It is equal to n1*n2/n, where n1<=n<=n2, 2*n1>n and n*2>n2. The rest should be easy.

Comment: could you please give me more explanation about how to expand ⌊lg n⌋+⌈lg n⌉ ?

Comment: @MR.NASS Dont expand logs, instead expand the exponentials. Here n1 and n2 are the upper and lower limits on n.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a derivation for the upper bound:

```
2^(⌊lg n⌋+⌈lg n⌉)/n
= 2^(2⌊lg n⌋+1)/n 
<= 2^(2 lg n + 1)/n
= 2^(2 lg n) 2^(1) / n
= 2 n^2 / n
= 2 n
= O(n)
```

So we know your function can be bounded above by 2*n. Now we do the lower bound:

```
2^(⌊lg n⌋+⌈lg n⌉)/n
= 2^(2⌈lg n⌉ - 1) / n
>= 2^(2 lg n - 1)/n
= 2^(2 lg n) 2^(-1) / n
= 1/2 n^2 / n
= 1/2 n
= O(n)
```

We now know that your function can be bounded below by n/2.

Checked on gnuplot; these answers look good and tight. This is a purely algebraic solution using the definition if floor() and ceiling() functions.